# I am building a TensorFlow graph using TensorFlow-rs and can’t get individual Operations from ops::split

Tags: c++, tensorflow, rust

I'm trying to complete this function:

```
///Split layers take in a single layer and splits it into a 
///vector of layers. Since all tensors are two dimensional,
///we can split with a single usize on axis=0.
fn split<O1: Into<Output>>(
    input: O1,
    num_splits: usize,
    scope: &mut Scope,
) -> Result<Vec<Output>, Status> {
    let num_splits_op = ops::constant(num_splits.into(), scope)?;
    let outputs = vec![];
    let split_outputs = ops::split(num_splits_op, input.into(), scope)?;
    //TODO: get vector of Outputs.

    Ok(outputs)
}
```

My problem is that *split_outputs* type is Operation. This makes sense because I am building the graph, but I cannot index Operation; I would have to fetch session run arguments to retrieve the TensorArray of Tensor types then index the fetched object and return each index.

I cannot find an indexing operation in the C++ API (which the Rust crate mirrors). Is there such an operation or is there another technique that can give me an operation for each sub-tensor in a given tensor produced by a split operation?

I need to create an Output or Operation for each sub tensor, essentially return each entry along axis=0 which should be a vector of Operations with length: num_splits when I am done writing the function.

Comment: Not sure it is relevant, but this seems very similar to the `chunks` method.

Comment: Kinda, split essentially is chunk for tensors. the problem I am having is that I need to return each "chunk" but its like Tensorflow-rs only returns an iter in the form of an Operation and I cannot find the method for getting N number of iters on the "sub-chunks".

Comment: Re *"spilt_outputs"*: Do you mean *"split_outputs"*?

Answer (score 0):

The shorthand functions are currently broken. I have raised issues as I’ve encountered them, but I solved with the following:

```
let axis_zero = ops::constant(0, scope)?;

let split_operation =
    ops::Split::new()
        .num_split(num_splits)
        .build(axis_one.clone(), input.0, scope)?;
```

If you can’t build an operation with a shorthand function, it is likely that a parameter isn’t being assigned via the shorthand function or *build_impl* the shorthand function is calling. You can fix this by method chaining the builder from an *ops::yourop::new()* method and then calling each parameter builder explicitly that isn’t in the *build_impl* or shorthand function as I have done here for *ops::Split*.

To solve my specific operation indexing problem, I create an Output type explicitly from each index in the split Operation:

```
// Create an output object for each split for graph connectionism
let mut outputs = vec![];
for i in 0..num_splits {
    outputs.push(Output {
        operation: split_operation.clone(),
        index: i as i32,
    });
}
Ok(outputs)
```

This explicitly avoids writing into a TensorArray and creates a graph edge for each "sub-tensor" split by the Split operation which is what I required.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this with a commit I wrote and the help and code review of the TF-rs SIG group. Consider Operation Instances for this which can be found in the auto generated documentation.

https://github.com/tensorflow/rust/commit/8bbf9f9234906a06a9635607d45b319d52897918